# Запуск BackgroundWorker из таймера c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте,
Подскажите пожалуйста у меня есть программа на visual c#

На форме есть datagridview который отображает информацию и кнопка обновления данной информации из базы.

Если я помещаю функцию, которая обновляет грид, в отдельный поток в событие 
BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) и при нажатии кнопки вызываю BackgroundWorker_DoWork.RunWorkerAsync() то грид замечательно обновляется и всё проходит хорошо.

Но если я запускаю BackgroundWorker_DoWork.RunWorkerAsync() из таймера который срабатывает периодически, то функция запускающая обновление грида срабатывает, но начинает ругаться на то, что я обращаюсь к datagridview из потока в котором его нет.

И при этом если запустить функцию обновления грида прямо из таймера, без использования BackgroundWorker, то тоже проходит всё хорошо.

Почему при запуски другого потока из таймера в нём не видны элементы формы приложения, а если стартуешь с кнопки то всё видно замечательно?

Answer (score 1):

А не легче использовать событийную модель?
Т.е. - метод читающий данные сообщает главному потоку о том что данные прочтены и передает их,и уже главный поток реализует их отображение?

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что Вы используете System.Threading.Timer вместо System.Windows.Forms.Timer.

Первый таймер работает в своём потоке, второй всё прокидывает в поток пользовательского интерфейса. А при запуске задачи BackgroundWorker привязывается к синхронизационному контексту того потока, в которой произошёл запуск задачи.

Comment: Я использовал как раз System.Windows.Forms.Timer.
Данную проблему решил установкой цикла с условием выхода по переменной.
Если поток инициируется при создании формы и внутри работает цикл, всё получается как доктор прописал.